# install XBMC – Kodi Media Center on kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, mediaplayer

I want to install XBMC – Kodi Media Center on linux
and I used these commands to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kodi
```

When I used the first command it shows me this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
software-properties-common is already the newest version (0.96.20.2-1).
software-properties-common set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
google-chrome-stable : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So what can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't and shouldn't.  Kali is a specific distro aimed at pentesting, and it would make no sense to set it up as a media center.

From [Kali official documentation](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux):

> Kali Linux is specifically geared to meet the requirements of professional penetration testing and security auditing. To achieve this, several core changes have been implemented in Kali Linux which reflect these needs:
>
> (...)
>
> A minimal and trusted set of repositories: given the aims and goals of Kali Linux, maintaining the integrity of the system as a whole is absolutely key. With that goal in mind, the set of upstream software sources which Kali uses is kept to an absolute minimum. Many new Kali users are tempted to add additional repositories to their sources.list, but doing so runs a very serious risk of breaking your Kali Linux installation.